# Do varchar/text/longtext columns in MySQL occupy full size in filesystem even for partially filled cells?

Tags: mysql, varchar

Do varchar/text/longtext columns in MySQL occupy full length size in filesystem even for incomplete cells?

Referring to [this blog article](http://boolean.co.nz/blog/max-length-for-mysql-text-field-types/135/) for example I have the following columns and i have put in a given string in it.

```
CHAR (72) - can store upto 72 characters - i put in a string "abcd"
VARCHAR (72) - can store upto 72 characters - i put in a string "abcd"
TINYTEXT - can store upto 255 characters - i put in a string "abcd"
TEXT - can store upto 65,535 characters - i put in a string "abcd"
LONGTEXT - can store upto 4,294,967,295 characters - i put in a string "abcd"
```

How much actual physical space will be occupied by each of these columns for a row? The full size upto which each column is capable of storing? Or only as much as required for storing "abcd"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'abcd' in `CHAR(72) CHARACTER SET ascii` occupies 72 bytes on disk.
'abcd' in `CHAR(72) CHARACTER SET utf8` occupies 3*72 bytes on disk.
'abcd' in `CHAR(72) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` occupies 4*72 bytes on disk.
'abcd' in `VARCHAR(72)` occupies 1+4 bytes on disk.
'abcd' in `TINYTEXT` occupies 1+4 bytes on disk.
'abcd' in `TEXT` occupies 2+4 bytes on disk.
'abcd' in `LONGTEXT` occupies 4+4 bytes on disk.

**Update**:  In some versions, InnoDB will store only 4 bytes for the `CHAR` cases.

Notes:
The 1,2,4 is for length; `VARCHAR` could be `2` in some situations.
The `CHARACTER SET` is important in all the cases, but does not impact the space occupied by 'abcd' except for `CHAR`.

@akuzminsky -- You are wrong about the *3.  `CHAR(N)` and `VARCHAR(N)` can hold up to N *characters* in the declared `CHARACTER SET`.  That will become up to 3*N bytes for `CHAR` or 1+3*N for `VARCHAR`.

`TEXT` is limited to 65535 *bytes* (plus 2-byte length).

There is overhead on top of the lengths described above.  In InnoDB, there are record flags, transaction ids, blocking factors, pointers to overflow areas, etc, etc.  So, if you use this kind of arithmetic, it will underestimate the disk space used.

MyISAM is more frugal; it has at least 1 byte of overhead per record; in some cases, only 1.

Comment: Why utf8 needs '3*72 bytes on disk'? Not all chars in UTF8 need multiple bytes.

Comment: @Maxim - `CHAR` is fixed length, so 3*72 is needed to handle any eventuality.  However, the documentation is unclear on whether InnoDB actually makes it variable length anyway.

Comment: What about UTF-8 characters occupying 4 bytes though?

Comment: @Trejkaz - In `VARCHAR`, each utf8mb4 _character_ takes between 1 and 4 _bytes_, depending on the character.  `CHAR` is a different matter.  For the full set of `UTF-8`, you need to specify `utf8mb4` in MySQL.

Comment: _Update_ -- There is some reason to believe that in _some_ situations, `CHAR(N)` does not occupy 3*N bytes.  (I am not ready to lay out the details -- it may depend on Engine, ROW_FORMAT, temp table, etc.)

Comment: Also note (from 5.1.20):  "Added a new PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH SQL mode. By default, trailing spaces are trimmed from CHAR column values on retrieval. If PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH is enabled, trimming does not occur and retrieved CHAR values are padded to their full length. This mode does not apply to VARCHAR columns, for which trailing spaces are retained on retrieval."

Answer (score 1):

And now, from the horse's mouth - the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html) - all you've ever wanted to know about how much storage is used per type. AFAIK, there is no function which will return the **storage** used - see below for length and char_length. You could possibly [devise a UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html) to do this, though I fail to see any pressing interest.

Storage Requirements for String Types (InnoDB tables).

In the following table, M represents the declared column length in characters for nonbinary string types and bytes for binary string types. L represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.

Data Type and Storage Required

- `CHAR(M)`    M × w bytes, 0 <= M <= 255, where w is the number of bytes required for the maximum-length character in the character set. See Section 14.2.6.7, “Physical Row Structure” for information about CHAR data type storage requirements for InnoDB tables.
- `BINARY(M)`  M bytes, 0 <= M <= 255
- `VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)`   L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 − 255 bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes
- `TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT` L + 1 bytes, where L < 2^8
- `BLOB, TEXT` L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16
- `MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT` L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24
- `LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT` L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32
- `ENUM('value1','value2',...)` 1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of enumeration values (65,535 values maximum)
- `SET('value1','value2',...)` 1, 2, 3, 4, or 8 bytes, depending on the number of set members (64 members maximum)

You might also be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length) -

```
LENGTH() returns the length of the string measured in bytes. 
CHAR_LENGTH() returns the length of the string measured in characters.
```

if you want to find the length in either bytes or characters of a given field.

Comment: That's okay. What you are taking about is the maximum allowed capacity. What i am asking about is, how much actual physical space will be occupied by the file system if a small string is stored in a column that can hold much larger string.

Comment: You have it. If, for example, you store 500 characters (ASCII) in a TEXT field, then you'll take up 502 (500 + 2)  bytes.

Comment: Small not: If CHAR(72) is UTF8 then it will be stored as VARCHAR(72*3)

Comment: guys.... talking about 500 characters or 72 characters is exceeding (or being equal to) the limits of VARCHAR (72). Can you _*please*_ provide examples with a simple string "abcd" as i mentioned in the question?

Comment: @akuzminsky - that's why I specified ASCII - also I mentioned length and character_length - if the data is stored as UTF8 (as most probably should be), then obviously you are correct.  To the OP, see my edit.

Comment: @Vérace, you are right. What  I mean is regardless actual content of CHAR(X) if it's UTF8 then it's VARCHAR(3*X)